# Как можно реализовать такой переключатель?

Tags: android

Подскажите это `SeekBar` или `RadioButton`? И как можно реализовать такой View-элемент?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это готовая библиотека [`RadioPager`](https://github.com/anton46/Android-RadioPager) от *Anton Nurdin Tuhadiansyah* и *Ronald Savianto*.

Если вам интересно, как она устроена - [смотрите исходники](https://github.com/anton46/Android-RadioPager/blob/master/src/id/co/anton19/radiopager/RadioPagerView.java) и все узнаете, на то он и OpenSorce